# Finding inverse function of $f(x)=10^x+5^x+1$

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

As the title of the question says , how to find $f^{-1}$ for this example ?

Of course $f$ is one-to one and with a simple transform it would be $y-1=5^x(2^x+1)$

$\Rightarrow \log_5(\dfrac{y-1}{2^x+1})=x$

Any hints for how to go further ?

Comment: I don't think there's an explicit inverse of this function in terms of standard functions. Where did you run into this problem?

Comment: One of my friends who attends in differential equations class this semester wanted me to solve this for her :) , 
She didn't tell me it was related to that topic so far , now I also guess its inverse function would not be explicit , as you said !

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't invert this analytically.

For large positive $x$, the first term dominates and $x=f^{-1}(y)\approx\log_{10}(y)$.

For large negative $x$, the first term is neglectible and $x=f^{-1}(y)\approx\log_5(y-1)$.

For small $x$, you can use a Taylor development limited to the second order

$$y=f(x)\approx3+x(\ln(10)+\ln(5))+\frac{x^2}2(\ln^2(10)+\ln^2(5)),$$

and solve for $x$.

Comment: Thanks! I got your solution and now I'm pretty sure there would be no analytical answer for this, but should I close this problem now ? or wait for some other solutions ?
The friend who gave me this problem believes there could be something to do with implicit functions, I have no idea myself !

Comment: Up to you, but you won't have a closed form solution.